# Google Chrome Arc Android App: Unable to play Video

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I am unable to play videos on arc with videoView.
The Videos are working on android devices and emulators.
tried local stored and online videos. Downloaded form youtube mp4 files and even they didn't work. Always get unable to play video alert.

Do you have information about this? Supported formats, encodings?

Thank You

Code:

```
 // Set video holder
        video_view = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        // Set URL
        Uri mySlideUri = Uri.parse(filelocation(this.videos.get(currentVideo).fileurl));

        mySlideUri=Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
        video_view.setVideoURI(mySlideUri);

      video_view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // Start video
        video_view.start();
```

Comment: @mr.icetea I added the code. I am also unable to play any videos in Webview as html5 video.

Comment: @mr.icetea do you have any idea?

Comment: Check the `INTERNET` permission. Did you declare it on `AndroidManifest`

Comment: yes of course I declared it.